# Is it possible for a React Virtualized list to snap to a full row when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a React Virtualized `<List>` component that's used as a drop-down menu.  I'd like the list to scroll a whole row at a time, like a normal OS-level menu, or at least snap to a whole row when the scrolling stops.

I've set `scrollToAlignment="top"`, thinking that might do it, but now I realized that messed up the scrolling behavior when setting `scrollToIndex`.

There's an `onScroll` event, and I suppose I could set a timeout to fire if another event wasn't received within a certain window, and then force the `scrollTop` to show a full row.  But I was hoping there might be a cleaner way to do it.

### Possible solution

Similar to brianvaughn's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46244961/4200446), I put together a solution using the `onScroll` event to call a debounced function that snaps the `scrollTop` to a whole row increment after a short delay:

```
const RowHeight = 45;

const ResultsList = React.createClass({
    list: null,

    snapRows: _.debounce(function(scrollTop)
    {
        this.list.scrollToPosition(Math.round(scrollTop / RowHeight) * RowHeight);
    }, 100),

    handleRef: function(ref)
    {
        this.list = ref;
    },

    onScroll: function(event)
    {
        this.snapRows(event.scrollTop);
    },

    rowRenderer: function(data)
    { ... },

    render: function()
    {
        var props = this.props;

        return <List
            ref={this.handleRef}
            width={490}
            height={450}
            rowCount={props.items.length}
            rowHeight={RowHeight}
            rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
            scrollToIndex={props.selectedIndex}
            onScroll={this.onScroll}
            {...props}
        />
    }
});
```

But I'm not really happy with it.  The snap at the end of the scroll is a bit distracting, and can feel a little weird if you're still holding on to the scrollbar thumb.

I think the only way to make it feel like you're updating a list of items rather than smoothly scrolling a page is to handle the scroll events and manually position the elements so the rows are always snapped to an even row increment.  I built a virtual list like that back in the days of IE5, but was hoping for a more modern implementation.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a use-case I've implemented before so I haven't given it much thought, but you *could* use a debounced `onScroll` or `onSectionRendered` handler to call [`scrollToCell`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md#scrolltocell--columnindex-number-rowindex-number-) and snap to a specific row.

**Edit**: Here's a rough example of what I'm talking about: https://codesandbox.io/s/545y634jxx

Comment: Thanks.  I tried something along the lines you suggested, and added that code to the post.  It works, but the snap at the end is a little distracting.  I think if I want to go in this direction I may need to handle the scrolling programmatically so that the rows shift only in whole row increments.

Comment: Understood. FWIW I added a link to a CodeSandbox demonstrating the technique I was referring to (although we probably understand each other pretty well). Just in case. :)

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't aware of codesandbox.io.  Looks handy.

Comment: sadly link is broken

Comment: Sorry. I suppose I didn't realize this one was linked to anywhere. Had to clear our my Code Sandbox links a while ago because there's a limited number per account.

Here's a quick recreation of it (if memory serves). I'll update the link in the original answer. https://codesandbox.io/s/545y634jxx